# Keras: using multiply cores in batch generator

Tags: python, linux, keras, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

I'm using following code to train model in `keras==2.1.6`:

```
history = model.fit_generator(
    generator=generator.batch_generator(is_train=True),
    epochs=config.N_EPOCHS,
    steps_per_epoch=100,
    validation_data=generator.batch_generator(is_train=False),
    validation_steps=10,
    verbose=1,
    shuffle=False,
    workers=args.n_thread,
    max_queue_size=args.n_thread*2,
    use_multiprocessing=True,
    callbacks=callbacks)
```

When I don't specify `use_multiprocessing=True` I have about 200% of CPU load in `htop` regardless what number `args.n_thread` is specifed, so `workers` parameter is useless in this case?

By default it uses thread based processing? But why number of threads, which should be related to `workers` parameters, not increase CPU load? is it related to GIL?

```
    use_multiprocessing: Boolean.
        If `True`, use process-based threading.
        If unspecified, `use_multiprocessing` will default to `False`.
        Note that because this implementation relies on multiprocessing,
        you should not pass non-picklable arguments to the generator
        as they can't be passed easily to children processes.
```

Also when using `use_multiprocessing=True` and for example `args.n_thread=6` in `htop` I see load average is more then 6 for 12 CPU system, is it because dataset preprocessing have some parallel code, i.e. some numpy operations, is it possible to use precisely 6 CPUS (600% CPU load)?

**Update:**
Looking at the keras code:
https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/30fe4ff1f12ff0c45bac8738b4d2690eadd056b2/keras/utils/data_utils.py#L409
it use `multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool` vs `multiprocessing.Pool` in both cases it uses `workers` parameter, so where from the difference come from?

Comment: There can be more cores involved, because other cores are running the training pipeline (feeding to gpu, etc.).

Comment: @FalconUA What is 'feeding to GPU'? these workers are actually get batches from batch generator.